# RestKit Response Can't Be Deserialzed to Object

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm having trouble mapping a response back to an object during a post request using RestKit.

Here's the code:

Request:

```
// mapping for the response. response is an object: {"response":"message","success":bool}
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[GenericResponse class]];
    [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"success",@"response"]];
    responseMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping pathPattern:@"/authenticate" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    // mapping for the request body
    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"username", @"password"]];
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[LoginCriteria class] rootKeyPath:nil];

    // set up the request
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"]];
    [manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:@"application/json"];

    // set up the LoginCriteria object
    LoginCriteria* loginCriteria = [LoginCriteria new];
    loginCriteria.password = @"test";
    loginCriteria.username = @"test";

    // make the request
    [manager postObject:loginCriteria path:@"/authenticate" parameters:nil
    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            GenericResponse *genericResponse = (GenericResponse*)mappingResult;
            NSLog(@"logged in: %@", [mappingResult array]);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"login failed");
    }];
```

GenericResponse.h:

```
@interface GenericResponse : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) Boolean* success;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* response;
@end
```

Log:

```
2012-12-17 15:44:22.890 Radiuus[8221:1703] T restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:139 POST 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate':
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en, fr, de, ja, nl, it, es, pt, pt-PT, da, fi, nb, sv, ko, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ru, pl, tr, uk, ar, hr, cs, el, he, ro, sk, th, id, ms, en-GB, ca, hu, vi, en-us;q=0.8";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    "User-Agent" = "Radiuus/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 6.0; Scale/1.00)";
}
request.body=(null)
2012-12-17 15:44:23.244 Radiuus[8221:5d0b] T restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:156 POST 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate' (200):
response.headers={
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 17 Dec 2012 20:44:23 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
}
response.body={"response":"authentication succeeded","success":true}
2012-12-17 15:44:23.246 Radiuus[8221:4f03] W restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:76 Adding mapping error: Expected an object mapping for class of type 'LoginCriteria', provider returned one for 'GenericResponse'
```

From the log, what's strange to me is that it seems that RestKit is expecting to deserialize the response to a LoginCriteria object, but is "failing" when it is correctly getting a GenericResponse object instead, which is of course correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had the same problem, and @AngeloS provides the solution below.  When using the postObject method, RestKit assumes that the response should be mapped back into the same class as the object that was posted, regardless of any response descriptors that you have registered with the object manager.  I'm not convinced that this is a very good assumption to make, as in many cases it doesn't make sense to return a copy of the entire object but instead a simple success message like in your code!

Comment: Agreed. Not sure I want to put potentially large amounts of data on the wire when all I need is true/false. This is especially a concern when considering mobile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for your answer to your question, as it lead me in the right direction to figure out how to use one of RestKit's built-in methods to solve this issue instead of modifying the core code.

From his documentation, https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping, in the **Handling Multiple Root Objects in Core Data Post/Put** section, he mentions that if you want to post one type of object, but receive another in the response, then you have to `nil` out the `targetObject` in the request operation.  A full example is missing from his documentation, so here is the block of code I used:

```
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [RKObjectManager.sharedManager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject: objectToBePOSTed method:RKRequestMethodPOST path: path parameters: params];
operation.targetObject = nil;
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    //handle success
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //handle failure
}];
[RKObjectManager.sharedManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

~ Happy Holidays

Comment: My holidays just got happier thanks to your answer. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with RestKit.
The resolve was to add mapping for the object that i was posting as a response too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried adding the LoginCriteria object as a response descriptor and I get the same error. Is this what you were suggesting to do?

Comment: Yes, like you have added for GenericResponse.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I did and it didn't work for me. I stepped through it and I saw two response descriptors being added, but when stepping through the deserialization process in `mapObject`, `[_mappingsDictionary count]` is always 1.

Comment: Did you check what object is in the mapping?
Hmmm, and what version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the RestKit code and found the following snippet in the `mapObject` function in `RKMapperOperation.m`:

```
if (NO == [[self.targetObject class] isSubclassOfClass:objectMapping.objectClass]) {
            if ([_mappingsDictionary count] == 1) {
                NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                          @"Expected an object mapping for class of type '%@', provider returned one for '%@'",
                                          NSStringFromClass([self.targetObject class]), NSStringFromClass(objectMapping.objectClass)];
                [self addErrorWithCode:RKMappingErrorTypeMismatch message:errorMessage keyPath:keyPath userInfo:nil];
                return nil;
            } else {
                // There is more than one mapping present. We are likely mapping secondary key paths to new objects
                destinationObject = [self objectWithMapping:mapping andData:mappableObject];
            }
        }
```

That first `if` statement checks to make sure that `targetObject` (the request object) has a class type that is in the hierarchy of `objectMapping.objectClass` (the response object). Since my request and response objects are different, this of course fails. I set a breakpoint at that line to prove it. Here's what is printed when I inspect:

```
(lldb) po self.targetObject
(id) $1 = 0x09fb54d0 <LoginCriteria: 0x9fb54d0>
(lldb) po objectMapping.objectClass
(Class) $2 = 0x00162c58 GenericResponse
```

As you can see, they are of different types, so this if succeeds and the function returns nil, leaving the response unmapped. I simply replaced `return nil;` with `destinationObject = [self objectWithMapping:mapping andData:mappableObject];` and everything works as expected.

I am unhappy with this solution since I don't feel that the author of RestKit intended for posts to send and receive different objects. Therefore, this is a hack. I'm leaving this unanswered until a) I hear a better solution, or b) the author of RestKit makes this change himself (or accepts mine :).